# Some questions about an application of Grauert's theorem and the Picard scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

The following is an exercise in Hartshorne.

Let $ k $ be an algebraically closed field, $ Y $ an integral scheme of finite type over $ k $ and $ f : X \rightarrow Y $ a flat projective morphism whose fibers are integral. Suppose $ L,M $ are line bundles on $X $ such that for every $ y \in Y $, $ L_y \cong M_y $ on the fiber $ X_y $. Then there is a line bundle $ N $ on $ Y $ such that $ L \cong M \otimes f^* Y $.

The proof is standard: We have $ \mathcal{F}_y = (L \otimes M^{-1})_y \cong \mathcal{O}_{X_y} $ for every $ y $, and hence for every **closed** point $ y $ we get $$ \text{dim}_{k(y)} H^0 (X_y, \mathcal{F}_y) = \text{dim}_{k(y)} H^0 (X_y, \mathcal{O}_{X_y})=1 $$ So Grauert's theorem applies and we get $ f_* \mathcal F $ is locally free of rank $ 1 $ on $ Y $. We can show easily then that this is a suitable choice of $ N $.

My question (1): Does Grauert's theorem need the constant dimension hypothesis for closed points only? Because neither the theorem statement or the proof indicates that. I don't know how to get $ \text{dim}_{k(y)} H^0 (X_y, \mathcal{O}_{X_y})=1 $ for an arbitrary point $ y $.

This result gives motivation for studying families of line bundles, i.e. studying the Picard scheme. We can take $ Y = S $ and $ X = V \times S $ for a projective variety $ V $ and then a family of line bundles on $ V $ parametrized by $ S $ is just a line bundle $ \mathcal L $ on $ V \times S $. And the exercise is the reason why the Picard functor is defined as $ \text{Pic}_V(S) := Pic(V \times S)/p^*Pic(S) $ where $ p : V \times S \rightarrow S $ is the projection.

My question (2): What if $ V $ is not a variety? Is the Picard functor representable for a non-reduced $ V $ say? (For non-singular varieties $ V $ it is.) What if $ k $ is not algebraically closed?

Comment: Your questions are very far apart and may be best asked as separate posts. For the first, recall that since the rank of a coherent sheaf on a noetherian scheme is upper-semicontinuous, the set where it has rank 2 or more is closed, and therefore must contain a closed point since you're working on a quasi-compact scheme. Thus checking at closed points is enough.

Comment: @KReiser why did I forget semicontinuity, such a good argument. A non-empty closed set of a q.c scheme always has a closed point.. so the rank > 1 locus is empty.

Comment: I'll leave the original post here anyway if someone can answer the second question.